# Get unique nested JSON keys with JQ

Tags: json, jq

How to get the unique keys from attributes key with JQ

```
{"id":1, "attributes":{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}}
{"id":2, "attributes":{"a": 4, "b": 5, "d": 6}}
{"id":3, "name":"ABC"}
```

Result like this
[
"a",
"b",
"c",
"d"
]

I'm try like this

```
jq '.attributes' test.json | jq -r '[inputs | keys[]] | unique | sort'
```

or

```
jq -r '[inputs.attributes | keys[]] | unique | sort' test.json
```

but getting error

**jq: error (at :11): null (null) has no keys**

Comment: Your second attempt is close. Use the `-n` option with `inputs` to also capture the first input, and use `? // {}` to streamline the case where `.attributes` is missing: `jq -n '[inputs.attributes? // null | keys[]] | unique | sort'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be using `reduce` on subsequent `inputs`:

```bash
jq 'reduce inputs.attributes as $a (.attributes; . + $a) | keys'
```

```
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d"
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/v-bat97apVr)

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of your second attempt:

```
jq -n '[inputs.attributes // empty | keys_unsorted[]] | unique'
```

The important point is that we have to take care of the case where there is no "attributes" key.

Note also that `unique` sorts, so (unless you're using gojq) we can use `keys_unsorted` to avoid redundant sorting.

Comment: Is there an advantage of using the null-input flag with `inputs` filter over using slurp (`-s`)? Readability? Performance? Why not `[., inputs]`? Trying to understand jq better.

Comment: Asked a new question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73843868/112968

Answer (score 0):

With slurp:

```
jq -s 'map(.attributes|keys?)|add|unique' test.json
```

- `-s` loads the input file as array
- `map(.attributes|keys?)` extracts only the keys (ignoring errors, such as trying to get keys of null)
- `add` merges all nested arrays into a single array (`[[1,2],[2,3]]` becomes `[1,2,2,3]`)
- `unique` sorts and removes duplicates