# Difference between slurp, null input, and inputs filter

Tags: performance, jq

Given the input document:

```json
{"a":1}
{"b":2}
{"c":3,"d":4}
```

What is the difference between the following jq programs (if any)? They all seem to produce the same output.

1. `jq '[., inputs] | map(to_entries[].value)'`
2. `jq -n '[inputs] | map(to_entries[].value)'`
3. `jq -s 'map(to_entries[].value)'`

In other words, the following (simplified/reduced) invocations seem identical:

- `jq '[.,inputs]'`
- `jq -n '[inputs]'`
- `jq -s '.'`.

How are they different? Are there scenarios where one works, but the others don't? Did older versions of jq not support all of them? Is it performance related? Or simply a matter of readability and personal preference?

---

Bonus points (added later to the question): does the same hold true for the following programs?

4. `jq '., inputs | to_entries[].value'`
5. `jq -n 'inputs | to_entries[].value'`
6. `jq -s '.[] | to_entries[].value'`
7. `jq 'to_entries[].value'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `jq '-n [inputs] ....'` and `jq '[.,inputs] ....'`, you are loading the whole file into memory.

A more memory-efficient way to achieve the result as an array is:

```
jq -n '[inputs | to_entries[].value]'
```

Answer (score 2):

Those first three programs are equivalent, both functionally and in terms of resource utilization, but they obscure the difference between array-oriented and stream-oriented programming.

In a nutshell, think `sed` and `awk`. For more details, see e.g. my [A Stream-oriented Introduction to jq](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq), and i.p. the section [On the importance of `inputs`](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq#on-the-importance-of-inputs).

---

> Bonus points: does the same hold true for the following programs:

Referring to the last four numbered examples in the Q: (4), (5) and (7) are essentially equivalent; (6) is just silly.

---

If you're looking for a reason why all these variations exist, please bear in mind that `input` and `inputs` were late additions in the development of jq.  Perhaps they were late additions because jq was originally envisioned as a very simple and for the most part "purely functional" language.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a little confused though, quoting the linked article: »Prior to the availability of inputs, it was necessary to “slurp” the entire file (as by using the -s command-line option), _which is inefficient, at least in the use of memory_.« I assume this only applies when using `reduce`, but I think this answer should mention it ("it" being `inputs` not requiring the whole file to be kept in memory for some cases).

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings: I see that `[inputs]` still loads everything, but `jq -n 'inputs | …'` is preferrable over `jq -s '.[] | …'`

Comment: @knittl - You wrote "I assume this only applies when using reduce", but as your subsequent comment (immediately above) illustrates, that is not the case.

Comment: Yes, I learned something in the 4 hours between those two comments :) I've also edited my question to include more details for future visitors who are wondering the same.

Comment: @knittl - In future, when editing a question, please find a way to do so without making answers to the original question problematic or confusing.  Having two sets of distinct programs, both labeled "(1), (2), (3)", is probably not a good idea anyway....

Comment: @knittl - No, I've fixed the numbering scheme, and updated my response accordingly.  Maybe we should delete our now-superfluous comments?

Comment: @knittl - Yes, perhaps there is a better approach, but at least it's not confusing.

Comment: Turns out markdown (at least on SO) can start lists at a different number. I've updated the Q and your A accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Adding even more cases for the sake of completeness:

From the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq):

> `--raw-input`/`-R`:
>
> Don't parse the input as JSON. Instead, each line of text is passed to the filter as a string. If combined with `--slurp`,  then  the  entire input is passed to the filter as a single long string.

This means that on one hand

- `jq -R -n '[inputs]'` and
- `jq -R '[., inputs]'`

both produce an array of strings, as each item provided by `inputs` (and `.` if it wasn't silenced by `-n`) corresponds to a line of text from the input document(s), whereas on the other hand

- `jq -R -s '.'`

slurps all characters from the input document(s) into exactly one long string, newlines included.