# jq: How to slurp mid-filter (convert separate json objects to an array)

Tags: jq

I am parsing Elastic logs that look like

```
$ cat my_log_file.txt:
{"level": "INFO", "message": "foo"}
{"level": "WARN", "message": "bar"}
{"level": "WARN", "message": "baz"}
```

Because they're one per line, formerly I have used `jq -s` to slurp them into an actual array that I can run `map` on:

```
jq -s 'map(.message) | unique' my_log_file.txt
```

Now I want to select out only lines that have level != "INFO". I should be able to just use [this cookbook recipe](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#filter-objects-based-on-the-contents-of-a-key), but again `jq` is having trouble with each line being a separate object and not in an array.

I can't use slurp, because it doesn't work with this command:

```
jq 'select(."level" != "INFO")' my_log_file.txt
```

But when I want to map to .message again, I get the same error I got before when I wasn't using slurp:

```
$ jq 'select(."level" != "INFO") | map(.message) | unique' my_log_file.txt
jq: error (at <stdin>:90): Cannot index string with string "message"
```

How can I convert my records midstream -- after the select is done, to convert the result from

```
{"level": "WARN", "message": "bar"}
{"level": "WARN", "message": "bar"}
```

to

```
[
  {"level": "WARN", "message": "bar"},
  {"level": "WARN", "message": "bar"}
]
```

I heard that `inputs` was designed to replace slurp, but when I tried

```
$ jq 'select(."level" != "INFO") | [inputs]' my_log_file.txt
```

that ignored my `select` and I had a list of every message again.

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way to make the selection while forming an array is to use `inputs` with the -n command-line option, along the lines of:

```
jq -n '[inputs | select(."level" != "INFO") ]' my_log_file.txt
```

So your query could be:

```
[inputs | select(."level" != "INFO") | .message] | unique
```

or to avoid the `sort` entailed by the call to `unique` and assuming all the .message values are strings:

```
INDEX(inputs | select(.level != "INFO"); .message)
| keys_unsorted
```

or even better:

```
INDEX(inputs | select(.level != "INFO") | .message; .)[]
```

If you want the array to be splatted, just append `[]`.

Comment: I feel like they should put in the documentation for `-s` that it can be replaced by `-n '[inputs]'`. Thanks, worked great.

Comment: @Noumenon I was wondering that too, which prompted me to ask [this question about the differences between slurp, -n option, and inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73843868/112968)

Comment: @knittl & Noumenon In combination with `--raw-input` (or `-R` for short) they do produce different results: `jq -R -n '[inputs]'` (and likewise `jq -R '[., inputs]'`) produces an array of strings, as each item provided by `inputs` (and `.` if it wasn't silenced by `-n`) corresponds to a line of text from the input document(s), whereas `jq -R -s '.'` on the other hand slurps all characters from the input document(s) into exactly one long string, newlines included.

Comment: @pmf that sounds like a useful addition to the other question. Could you add that as answer there?

Comment: @knittl [Done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74244367/2158479).

Answer (score 1):

> I can't use slurp, because it doesn't work with this command

If you use slurp, you'll need to wrap the `select` in a `map()` to make it work:

```
jq -s 'map(select(.level != "INFO"))' my_log_file.txt
```

---

So to get all the unique `message` where `level != "INFO"`, you can use:

```
jq -s 'map(select(.level != "INFO").message) | unique[]' my_log_file.txt
```

That will output:

```
"bar"
"baz"
```

As you can test in [this online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/U43lZfKS48R).

Comment: Thanks, it works. What is the meaning of `unique[]`? It looks like it's saying "give me the uniques as an array" but it does the opposite, turns them from an array into just lines.

Comment: That's confusing that map() apparently runs before select(). I would have assumed if `jq -s 'select'` fails, that `jq -s 'map(select(` would fail. If "select works on an array", why doesn't it need `-s` (which gives you a JSON array, with brackets)?

Comment: @noumenon - The text you are referring to has been clarified.  jq's `select` applies the selection criterion to its input directly, no matter what that input might be.