# reducing stream data to single result without putting them all into memory

Tags: jq

I can reduce produced lines like:

```
seq 5 | jq --slurp ' reduce .[] as $i (0;.+($i|tonumber))'
```

to get

```
15
```

but this put whole input into memory, I don't want that. Following:

```
seq 5 | jq ' reduce . as $i (0;.+($i|tonumber))'
```

produces incorrect output

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

similar happens when foreach is used.

What is correct syntax?

Comment: Note a dupe, but related: [Difference between slurp, null input, and inputs filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73843868/112968)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`inputs`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#inputs) instead of the context `.`, along with the `--null-input` (or `-n`) [option](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) so the context wouldn't eat up the first item:

```bash
seq 5 | jq -n 'reduce inputs as $i (0;.+($i|tonumber))'
```

```
15
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Gp89gk9V62z)

Explanation: If you just use `.` as context, your filter will be executed once for each input (five times in this case, hence five outputs, each summing up just one value). Providing the `-n` option sets the input to `null`, so the filter is executed only once, while `input` and `inputs` sequentially read in another/all new items from the input stream.

Comment: thanks, can you explain, why it's different and what is happening behind scenes?