# How to merge multiple results in jq? The array construction provided by default is not very convenient

Tags: linux, syntax, jq

For example, there is a group_by_count script.

```
jq 'map(select(.sno|startswith("20")))|group_by(.school)[]|{k:.[0].school,len:length}'
```

The output of this command has multiple results like:

```
{k:xxx,len:111}{k:aaa,len:22}...
```

If you want to merge these results into a single array, you need to wrap the entire expression with brackets `[]`. For example, you would write:

```
jq '[map(select(.sno|startswith("20")))|group_by(.school)[]|{k:.[0].school,len:length}]'
```

Notice the top level `[]`.

This can be a bit cumbersome, especially in a terminal environment where moving the cursor can be inconvenient. Is there a simpler method, such as using the command:

```
jq 'map(select(.sno|startswith("20")))|group_by(.school)[]|{k:.[0].school,len:length} | merge'
```

This way, for the user, it would be a matter of "appending" without the need to move the cursor.

Expected output：

```json
[
  {
    "k": "xxx",
    "len": 111
  },
  {
    "k": "aaa",
    "len": 22
  }
]
```

Comment: expected output：
[ {k:xxx,len:111}, {k:aaa,len:22} ]

Comment: Show us your input file

Comment: '''
[
  {
    "sno": "201202124",
    "name": "jack",
    "birth": "1988-05-05",
    "school": "x",
    "class": "c1",
    "major": "xyz",
    "id": "xxx",
    "sex": "0"
  },
  {
    "sno": "201202125",
    "name": "bob",
    "birth": "1988-08-18",
    "school": "x",
    "class": "c1",
    "major": "",
    "id": "123123",
    "sex": "0"
  }
]
'''
like this.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to merge these results into a single array, you need to wrap the entire expression with brackets [].

One way to avoid having to do so would be to avoid using `[]` after the call to `group_by`, so your filter would end with:

```
group_by(.school) | map({k:.[0].school, len:length})
```

However, since the jq program is quite long anyway, you probably
should consider putting it into a file and use jq's -f option.

For the record, it might be worth mentioning that if you're working at the command prompt and find yourself in the situation described, you can always simply pipe the stream into `jq -s`.

Comment: Thanks! `map` is  useful for many case. I forgot to use it earlier, probably because I'm not very familiar with jq. ^_^

Comment: Re "long program": With Unix-Shells you can use a single-quoted string spanning multiple lines instead.

Comment: @A.H. There are many things that can be done, but the OP seems not to have wanted to bother with moving the cursor.

Comment: @EulerTao the program from your question already uses `map` (in a different place) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a POSIX shell, you can pipe the output to another jq invocation:

```
jq '..... your long jq program producing a stream of object .....' | jq -s
```

`-s` is "slurp", which will put all objects from the input stream into a single array. [An alternative is appending `jq -n '[inputs]'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73843868/difference-between-slurp-null-input-and-inputs-filter)